# Taking input of unknown size of array

Tags: arrays, c, input, scanf, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int a[50],i,n=0;
    while(scanf("%d",&a[n++])!=EOF);
    n--;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Let,

Input: 5 6 7 8 9

Output: 5 6 7 8 9

My question is why the above code works in Online C Compiler and gives proper EOF(-1)

But while running the code in offline C IDE like Codeblocks, it results in an infinite loop of input as it is not giving any EOF, and what to do to get a similar result in an offline compiler?

Comment: Isn't it because **you** are not giving any EOF (Ctrl+Z on Windows or Ctrl+D on Linux)?

Comment: As an alternative to: `while(scanf("%d",&a[n++])!=EOF);` you can do `while(scanf("%d",&a[n++])==1);`. Then the loop will stop at the first non-integer input.

Comment: You should also check that `n` is always less than 50

Comment: Also adding size check is good: `while(n < 50 && scanf("%d",&a[n++])==1);`

Comment: Another reason to check the specific `1` from `scanf` is that if you enter data it cannot convert you'll go into an infinite loop, since `0 != EOF` too.

Comment: Suppose I give 10 inputs, it should stop the loop after 10 inputs, right? I've checked with the conditions also like checking return types -1,0,1, still, it's not working. Also, I know that Ctrl+Z will work but I was asking without using the Ctrl+Z, is it possible?

Comment: If the 10 inputs are from a file that has been directed as the program's input, yes. The loop ends when `EOF` is returned. There is no magic 10 stopper, so if you are typing the inputs, no.

Comment: Yes, there is no magic 10 stopper XD... So typing the inputs won't work, right? And Thanks to Everyone

Comment: See https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/146300-how-input-eof-code-blocks.html#:~:text=You%20can%20trigger%20EOF%20at,Z%20on%20a%20new%20line.&text=So%20how%20should%20I%20run%20my%20.&text=When%20I%20press%20CTRL%2BZ,with%20the%20window%20still%20open.

Comment: regarding: `int a[50],i,n=0;`  The variable `i` is hidden/shadowed inside the `for()` loop,  Since the `i` is not used anywhere else, that variable 'should' be eliminated. suggest: `int a[50];  int n=0;`

Comment: OT: the posted code contains a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 50.  'magic' number numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf()` function returns the number of input values it scanned.

In case of input error or failure it returns `EOF`.
As suggested in the comments you can compare the `scanf()` return value to 1 in order to see if it had a valid input. So if your input is anything other than an `int` it will end the loop.

Also making sure `n` is still within the array bounds before calling the `scanf()` is a good idea.

So you can write the code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int a[50], n = 0;

    while((n < 50) && (scanf("%d", &a[n++]) == 1));

    n--;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```